# Is it possible to create a ruby gem that when added to a rails project simply appends code to its initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, monkeypatching, initializer

I've got some helper code (monkey patches) I tend to carry around from rails project to rails project via simply copying files or pasting code into the initializers folder.

I think a clean way to deploy different categories of my initalizer code would be to simply add gems to my project Gemfile that would do the equivalent of this for me. I'm not very skilled at creating gems or the deeper side of ruby on rails engineering so I just wanted to know if this were possible before I got started with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. It should be probably enough to make a simple gem, put your monkey-patches there and require them in the gem entry point (e.g., if the gem is called `foobar`, then `bundler` will require `lib/foobar.rb` by default).

There is [a guide on creating gems](http://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/creating_gem.html) available in Bundler docs. In case you need to interact with Rails application configuration, you can take a look at [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).